# Class of Enum of any type generic construction

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm totally confused with java generics now trying to resolve the following thing.

I have the function:

```
private static Enum<?> findEnumValue(final Class<Enum<?>> cls, final Object value) 
{
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (value instanceof Enum<?>) {
        return (Enum<?>) value;
    }
    if (value instanceof String) {
        for (Enum<?> item : cls.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (item.name().equals(value)) {
                return item;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I'm trying to pass to this function an ordinary enum, say, `Name` and it's value `JOHN` like this:

`findEnumValue(Name.class, Name.JOHN.name())`

but this doesn't work. Could somebody, please, point me to my mistakes and explain what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the Name enum:

```
public enum Name  {
    JOHN,
    MARK;
}
```

Thanks you all for help!

Comment: *"this doesn't work"* Please avoid such statements without detailing.

Comment: Can you post the code for Name class ?

Comment: @m0skit0, sorry, compiler complains about this statement. But it's message doesn't provice any sensible information.

Comment: It searchs for JOHN in Name class but what is Name class?

Comment: Maybe not to you, what's the error message?

Comment: @m0skit0, Here is the compiler error: `findEnumValue(final Class<Enum<?>> cls, final Object value) cannot be applied to (Name.class, String)`. Thanks for patience.

Comment: It is really strange, how many times i look the code it seems valid to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static <T extends Enum<T>> T findEnumValue(final Class<T> cls,
        final Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (value.getClass() == cls) {
        return cls.cast(value);
    }
    if (value instanceof String) {
        return Enum.valueOf(cls, (String)value);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think your answer, @JoopEggen, is the best, though Alex explained what is the problem in general, you explained it with use of code. It's clear for mw now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` instead of `Class<Enum<?>>`. `Name.class` is not a `Class<Enum<?>>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static <T extends Enum<T>> T findEnumValue(final Class<T> cls, final Object value) 
    {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (value instanceof Enum<?>) {
            return (T) value;
        }
        if (value instanceof String) {
            for (T item : cls.getEnumConstants()) {
                if (item.name().equals(value)) {
                    return item;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```